How long does an Indian visa ban last after overstaying your previous visa?
Due to personal reasons, I overstayed my visa in India for a while and then left on an exit permit granted by the FRRO after paying fines and clearing myself. After like a year, I applied for a visa again via my local embassy, only to find out that I have been blacklisted and therefore can't get a visa.
The embassy doesn't know how long this ban will last. How do I find out how long I've been banned for and also how do I get myself off this list, considering I never committed any crimes during my stay and paid penalties for overstaying?

According to this blog the minimum length is 2-5 years, and you’ll need help from an immigration lawyer to get your name removed.
